# Using lets encrypt without control over the root directory

Tags: django, apache, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm running a Django website and using lets encrypt for my SSL.  Configuration of the framework is such that I can't allow access on: http://url.com/.xxxx

What I can allow free access to is:
http://url.com/static/.xxxx

My /static/ URL can accept and host any random files lets encrypt needs.  Is there a way to have certbot support /static/ instead of just using / for the URL?

Thanks

## EDIT

I've found a work around that is acceptable for me.  Further digging, I found that /.well-known/ is always the base directory for SSL checking.  That means we can add a static directory which will work nicely with certbot.  Here's how, firstly add this into your apache config:

```
Alias /.well-known/ /var/www/XXXXX/website/static/.well-known/
<Directory /var/www/XXXXX/website/static/.well-known/>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then add this into your settings.py file:

```
STATIC_ENCRYPT_URL = '/.well-known/'
STATIC_ENCRYPT_ROOT = '/var/www/XXXXX/website/static/'
```

Add this into your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
  ... 
] + static(settings.STATIC_ENCRYPT_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ENCRYPT_ROOT)
```

Reset your webserver.  Now you have a special url /.well-known/ which will host any file certbot requires.

I'd still like a better answer than this.

Comment: Disable django temporarily, and run a simple file TCP server.

Comment: That will work fine on dev, but I can't take the production server offline like that.

Comment: It takes less than 2 minutes for the entire LetsEncrypt process. You could also try using CloudFlare's free plan for ssl.

Comment: Please only submit valid suggestions that are on topic.  There will be others with this same problem, and they also need information on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Let's Encrypt uses (their version of) the (still being standardised) ACME protocol so the challenges will always appear in /.well-known/acme-challenge/

The /.well-known/ prefix is reserved by the IETF for uses like this, if favicon.ico or robots.txt were invented today, they'd be in /.well-known/

Comment: the `urlpatterns` addition is to your project urls.py file and not an app urls.py file, yes?

Comment: @brf that is correct

Answer (score 5):

**In case other users come this way like I did from Google, here's how I improved this situation:**

I was unsatisfied by my options when it came to creating `ACME` challenges for Let's Encrypt when running a `Django` application. [So, I rolled my own solution and created a Django app!](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-letsencrypt) Basically, you can manage your `ACME` challenges as just another object, and the app will produce the proper end-point URL.

Simply [`pip install django-letsencrypt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-letsencrypt) and follow the [`README`](https://github.com/urda/django-letsencrypt/blob/release/README.rst) to be on your way.